# `if [-e file.txt]` not working in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to check if a file exists using bash. This is my code

```
if [-e file.txt]; then
  echo "file exists"
else
  echo "file doesn't exist"
fi
```

But when I run it I get:

```
./test.sh: line 3: [-e: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`[` is not a special token in Bash; it's just that the *word* `[` is a builtin command (just like `echo`). So you need a space after it. And, similarly, you need a space before `]`:

```
if [ -e file.txt ] ; then
```

That said, I recommend `[[ ]]` instead — it's safer in a few ways (though it still requires the spaces):

```
if [[ -e file.txt ]] ; then
```

Comment: +1. Just note that `[[` is a bash feature, so you cannot invoke your script with `/bin/sh`

Comment: Could edit your answer to explain WHY double square brackets is safer please?

Answer (score 3):

```
if [ -e file.txt ]; then
```

You need spaces.
**[** and **]** are regular programs.

Comment: to be pedantic, `]` is not a program, it is the required last argument for the `[` command

Comment: you are right @glennjackman !

Answer (score 2):

Woops, turns out I needed a space between `[` and `-e`. Like this:

```
if [ -e file.txt ]; then
  echo "file exists"
else
  echo "file doesn't exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

the '[' and ']' needs to be 'on--their-own', i.e. surrounded by spaces.

```
if [ -e file.txt ] *emphasized text*; then
  echo "file exists"
else
  echo "file doesn't exist"
fi
```